# FB Messenger API - Receiving double requests

Tags: ruby, facebook, api, httpresponse, facebook-messenger

I have a working FB Bot built with Ruby which allows players to play a scavenger hunt.

Sometimes though, when I have multiple players in a team, FB is sending me a players 'Answer' webhook twice. I have looked into it and at first thought it was to do with the 20 second timeout if FB gets no 200 OK response ([Docs here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhook#response)). After checking the logs though, I am receiving the second webhook from FB only 14 seconds later. See below:

```
# Webhook #1 
{"object"=>"page", "entry"=>[{"id"=>"252445748474312", "time"=>1532153642358, "messaging"=>[{"sender"=>{"id"=>"1709242109154907"}, "recipient"=>{"id"=>"252445748474312"}, "timestamp"=>1532153641935, "message"=>{"mid"=>"0FeOChulGjuPgg3YJqEgajNsY8kMfNRt_bpIdeegEeE54h-KB8szcd-EQ-UHUT3850RwHgH4TxVYFkoFwxqhtg", "seq"=>402953, "text"=>"Larrikins"}}]}]}

# Webhook #2 (14 seconds later)
{"object"=>"page", "entry"=>[{"id"=>"252445748474312", "time"=>1532153656901, "messaging"=>[{"sender"=>{"id"=>"1709242109154907"}, "recipient"=>{"id"=>"252445748474312"}, "timestamp"=>1532153641935, "message"=>{"mid"=>"0FeOChulGjuPgg3YJqEgajNsY8kMfNRt_bpIdeegEeE54h-KB8szcd-EQ-UHUT3850RwHgH4TxVYFkoFwxqhtg", "seq"=>402953, "text"=>"Larrikins"}}]}]}
```

Notice both are exactly the same apart from the first "time" attribute (14 secs later).

Due to a number of methods and calls that I process after receiving the first webhook, the 200 OK response is only being sent back to FB once I have finished sending my messages in response (hence the 14 second delay).

So I have two questions:

1. Is the 14 second delay too long and that is why FB is resending? If so, how can I send a 200OK response straight away (`head :ok`)?
2. Is it another issue entirely?

Comment: If it takes you 14 seconds to figure out what to respond with in the first place, then you can not send an “OK” response any earlier; that would only make sense if you can respond to the user’s message quicker, but have additional operations to perform on the received data that take longer (but can be performed in the background, or after responding and closing the connection.)

Comment: @CBroe right that is what I was thinking. I thought maybe I run some background jobs to speed up the 14 seconds. Not sure if that may ruin the instant 'chat' experience though. 

Still not convinced it's the 14 seconds that is causing FB to resend though as the timeout is apparently 20?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/policy/responsiveness#policy mentions 30 seconds within which automated bots must respond - but that is more a policy regarding user experience, not necessarily regarding technical limitations. Maybe try to log your response times (diff between webhook udpate received and your 200 response), and check if there is any time-based correlation to what you get "double updates" for as a first measure, to verify whether that's the reason or something else?

Comment: Yup I did the above and the correlation I found was that all "double updates" happen because the initial webhook always takes about 12 + seconds to send out a 200 OK. 

I'm sending multiple messages in response to the first webhook in my methods and I'm guessing it will only return 200 OK once my app is finished sending all those messages. Seem like the only way to speed it up is to use delayed jobs and thus send 200 OK response quicker?

Comment: Did you ever find the cause? I'm facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

You also ensure that "Echo" is disabled.

Go to Settings>Webhooks, edit events.

[image]

Asyncronous language like NodeJS is recomended, in my case y work with AWS SQS, I have workers that process the requests witout blocking (dont wait), I return 200,"ok" to FB to avoid that FB send again the message to my webhook.

Anothe apporach maybe store the *mid* in database, and check in each request if the *mid* exists, if exists the dont process the message. I was use Dynamo DB (AWS) with TTL enabled, thus with TTL my database *autoclean* every hour erasing old request.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the 15 second wait before replying, was also happening to me as Facebook auto retries when you don't reply fast enough. Te EEe Te's idea is solid, write some mechanism to cache mids and check if it is a duplicate before processing